# Reference request: Transverse parabolic Schauder estimates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators

Is there a version of the parabolic Schauder estimates for transversely parabolic linear PDE's on a manifold with a Riemannian foliation for functions that are constant on the leaves of the foliation? If so, could you provide a reference? Many thanks!